# Total the hours worked, then filter out 30mins where the segment per datekey contains lunch

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Shifts, below is a sample of the data

```
ID Key  DateKey  Start                End                  Hours     Segment 
1  1001 20210101 2021-01-01 09:00:00  2021-01-01 09:00:00  4.000000  On-Call
2  1001 20210101 2021-01-01 11:00:00  2021-01-01 11:15:00  0.250000  Break
3  1001 20210102 2021-01-02 13:00:00  2021-01-01 19:00:00  6.000000  On-Call
4  1001 20210102 2021-01-02 15:00:00  2021-01-01 15:15:00  0.250000  Break
5  1001 20210102 2021-01-02 17:00:00  2021-01-01 17:30:00  0.500000  Lunch
6  1001 20210103 2021-01-03 09:00:00  2021-01-03 16:00:00  7.000000  On-Call
7  1001 20210103 2021-01-03 11:00:00  2021-01-03 11:15:00  0.250000  Break
8  1001 20210103 2021-01-03 13:00:00  2021-01-03 13:30:00  0.500000  Lunch
9  1002 20210104 2021-01-04 09:00:00  2021-01-04 09:00:00  4.000000  On-Call
10 1002 20210104 2021-01-04 11:00:00  2021-01-04 11:15:00  0.250000  Break
11 1002 20210105 2021-01-05 07:00:00  2021-01-05 14:00:00  7.000000  On-Call
12 1002 20210105 2021-01-05 09:00:00  2021-01-05 09:15:00  0.250000  Break
13 1002 20210105 2021-01-05 11:00:00  2021-01-05 11:30:00  0.500000  Lunch
```

I'm trying to:

1. Total the hours per DateKey e.g DateKey 20210101 and ID 1 and 2 total hours worked is 4.250000.
2. After totalling the hours worked for that day subtract 30mins from the total work hours if the segment for that datekey contains lunch e.g 20210102 total hours worked ( ID 3,4,5 ) is 6.750000 subtract 30mins.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I'm trying to total the Hours worked for each employee, the key column is the unique identifier, and the datekey is the day of work......where there's lunch in the segment for the employee schedule I want to minus the lunchtime then total the hours worked for that day. if there's no lunch in the employee daily segment then don't minus the lunch time but total the hours worked.

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` query with `CASE` expression on the `Segment`

Comment: Total the hours: `Select Key, Datekey, sum(Hours)`.  Filter out unpaid lunch: `Where Segment <>'Lunch'`.  For each employee  & day: `Group By Key, Datekey`.  This is simple SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Group data on datekey, then sum it without lunch 
select datekey,sum(hours)[total]
from newtbl
where segment!='lunch'
group by datekey
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how do I subtract 30min from the total hours worked for those Employees with lunch I their record  e.g the Employee with datekey 20210102 total hours worked is 6.750000 then subtract 30mins ( there is a segment lunch in their record for that day ), the Employee with datekey 20210105 total hours worked is 7.750000 then subtract 30mins ( there is a segment lunch in their record for that day as well ).

Comment: @SQLGrab This is a poor answer because it has no explanation. But if you don't include the lunch rows in your sum, then you don't need to "subtract" anything. Also note that the code does not match your requirements since it does not group by both Key and DateKey. For some strange reason, poster has changed the name of the table to add confusion.

Answer (score 0):

to find total hours per columns, I would use something like this:

```sql
Select Key,sum(hours) from Shifts where DateKey == 20210101;
```

to exclude the lunchtime from total work:

```sql
SELECT  key,sum(hours) FROM Shifts where  seg <> "lunch" GROUP by key
```

Comment: Multiple syntax errors, left out the DATEKEY requirement, etc.